# use autodesk forge api to get "mass properties" but got nothing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Using the autodesk forge api , first I got a access_token and create a bucketkey and then upload a stl file and then verify the job is complete and then got the guid. use the access_token, urn , guid I post a call :

> curl -X 'GET' -H 'Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJTRmxONGFFOTMzZ0dkU1FzbFZzbXk0TlZZTFNsSnc1dyIsImV4cCI6MTQ5OTQ3OTg4NCwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpjcmVhdGUiLCJidWNrZXQ6cmVhZCJdLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJiWUE0TWRSc3VlazVnQlZsV3lwMmwydDN6SllvOXVnMjR4VEI2TmtZUld5YTdPT0NVOWU2c3JGcEk0UWRTWHFJIn0.ckLsWxfaUUa_zY2UDumUApxcDZR6xfCRE18GCHvIpPc'
>   -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtamF2YS1zYW1wbGUtYXBwLXNmbG40YWU5MzNnZ2RzcXNsdnNteTRudnlsc2xqdzV3LzIwMTcwNzA4MDkxMTU2NTkwMjgzMC5zdGw/metadata/a1f8def6-4c68-4bac-8c88-d14353252d67/properties'

As describe in the tutorials of autodesk: I should got the "mass properties" like volume and area, but I got neither of the two:

> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true <
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * < Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8 < Date: Sat, 08 Jul 2017 01:15:18 GMT < Server: Apigee
>   Router < x-ads-app-identifier:
>   platform-viewing-2017.03.08.15.bf43c23-production < x-ads-duration:
>   181 ms < x-ads-startup-time: Wed Jun 21 05:40:27 UTC 2017 <
>   Content-Length: 387 < Connection: keep-alive <
>   * Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact {"data":{"type":"properties",  "collection":[
>     {"objectid":1,"name":"201707080911565902830",
>         "properties":{"Name":"201707080911565902830"}},
>     {"objectid":2,"name":"201707080911565902830",
>         "properties":{"Component
>   Name":"201707080911565902830","Name":"201707080911565902830"}},
>     {"objectid":3,"name":"mesh_name_undefined",
>         "properties":{"Appearance":"191, 191,
>   191","Name":"mesh_name_undefined"}}]}}

Any help is appreciate, tks to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This endpoint simply returns the properties that are extracted from the native seed file, it doesn't compute for you mass, volume and so on. I don't think those physical properties are part of the STL file, so you won't see them either with /properties endpoint.

If you upload for example an Inventor or dwf file, you will see properties that are attached to that file. To do a simple test upload your file to our viewer https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer and look at what properties are available using the properties panel, that the same you will get from the endpoint.

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: You are right , a STL file is Composed of triangles, and a STL file doesn't not contain  properties like area or volume.  So  there is nothing wrong with this api . By the way , is there some method I can use to calculate the volume and area from forge, or just use the svf file to calculate area and volume.  tks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct way to compute such values directly with forge, as you mention you could load the model in the viewer and use THREE.js API to compute volume from the meshes, this cannot be performed server-side because you need a browser. Alternatively you could use ModelDerivatives to export to .obj and compute from the .obj, I bet there are librairies that can handle that. The downside is that exporting to .obj in Forge costs cloud credits.